# Is it possible to JSDoc a custom EventEmitter with the event's proper callback params?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, eventemitter

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045000/how-do-i-jsdoc-custom-eventemitter-on-events-in-visual-studio-code). However, even though it lists all the possible events, it doesn't include the callback params when I chose an event to listen to.

Here's a sample code

```
class BotClient extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
    };
    
    /**
     * @typedef {['ready' | 'messageCreate', ...any[]]} ClientEventsList
     */

    /**
     * @param {ClientEventsList} eventArg
     */
    addListener(...eventArg) {
        super.addListener(...eventArg);
    };
    /**
     * @param {ClientEventsList} eventArg
     */
    on(...eventArg) {
        super.on(...eventArg);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [`tiny-typed-emitter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-typed-emitter) package. [It doesn't add any overhead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-typed-emitter#no-overhead).

> Library adds no overhead. All it does is it simply reexports renamed `EventEmitter` with customized typings. You can check [`lib/index.js`](https://github.com/binier/tiny-typed-emitter/blob/66c1b66bc159675352a6f38911e4c6cf2117f3e4/lib/index.js) to see the exported code.

And then declare `BotClient` in javascript with JSDocs as so:

```js
const { TypedEmitter } = require("tiny-typed-emitter");

/**
 * @extends {TypedEmitter<{
     'ready': (value: boolean) => void
     'messageCreate': (message: string) => void
   }>}
 */
class BotClient extends TypedEmitter {
  constructor() {
      super();
  };
};
```

This way both the event and the event's arguments are going to be typed.

**index.js**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, and I would like to share it:

```js
import { Writable } from 'stream'


/**
 * @template {Writable['on'] & (name: 'custom', listener: (value: string) => void) => this} Listener
 * @template {Writable['emit'] & (name: 'custom', value: string) => boolean} Emitter
 */
class Custom extends Writable {
  constructor () {
    // EVENTS
    /** @type {Listener} */
    this.addListener = super.addListener
    /** @type {Emitter} */
    this.emit = super.emit
    /** @type {Listener} */
    this.on = super.on
    /** @type {Listener} */
    this.once = super.once
    /** @type {Listener} */
    this.prependListener = super.prependListener
    /** @type {Listener} */
    this.prependOnceListener = super.prependOnceListener
    /** @type {Listener} */
    this.removeListener = super.removeListener
    /** @type {Listener} */
    this.off = super.off
  }
}

export default Custom
```

<del>This approach doesn't just work with events, you can use it to basically overload any class method!</del>
**Edit:** While it works with VSCode intellisense, it doesn't play nice with the `tsc` compiler; it just ignores any property that exists on the super class, that means the produced `d.ts` files don't include them unfortunately.